# Converting Double to Int in C Problem

Tags: c, int, double

```
int main(void)
{
    double dollars;
    int count;

    /* Get amount of money and make sure it's in range */
    printf("Enter an amount up to $100.00: ");
    scanf("%lf",&dollars);
    while(dollars <= 0 || dollars > 100) {
        printf("Re-enter an amount: ");
        scanf("%lf",&dollars);
    }

    /* Convert money to 2 decimal places */
    dollars = (int) (dollars * 100) / 100.00;
    printf("\nAmount entered: $%.2lf\n\n", dollars);
    printf("Change breakdown:\n");

    /* Determine amount of $20.00s */
    count = dollars / 20;
    if(count > 1)
        printf("%i $20.00s\n", count);
    else if(count == 1)
        printf("%i $20.00\n", count);
    dollars = dollars - (count * 20);

    /* Determine amount of $10.00s */
    count = dollars / 10;
    if(count > 1)
        printf("%i $10.00s\n", count);
    else if(count == 1)
        printf("%i $10.00\n", count);
    dollars = dollars - (count * 10);

    /* Determine amount of $5.00s */
    count = dollars / 5;
    if(count > 1)
        printf("%i $5.00s\n", count);
    else if(count == 1)
        printf("%i $5.00\n", count);
    dollars = dollars - (count * 5);

    /* Determine amount of $1.00s */
    count = dollars / 1;
    if(count > 1)
        printf("%i $1.00s\n", count);
    else if(count == 1)
        printf("%i $1.00\n", count);
    dollars = dollars - (count * 1);


    /* Determine amount of pennies */
    /* NOT WORKING if 55.41 is inputted count becomes 40 instead of 41 */
    count = dollars / 0.01;
    printf("\n\n%i",count);
    printf("\n%lf\n\n",dollars / 0.01);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Read this: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html

Comment: What's your question, and how have you tried to solve your problem thus far?

Comment: Yeah I've been stuck on this for a long time trying to get the double to convert to the correct integer

Comment: Look at the last comment in the code

Comment: You should aim to use a data structure (probably an array) to handle $20, $10, $5, $1 (and you can get $100 and $50 bills/notes too).  And you might be wanting to know that the coins in the US are 25¢, 10¢, 5¢ and 1¢.  For the rest, you need to understand that floating point numbers are an approximation to the mathematical concept.  You would probably do best to convert the value into an integer number of pennies with rounding:  `pennies = (100 * dollars + 0.5);`

Comment: I would suggest not using `double`s. Use an `int` and store the number of cents. To read/write amounts of dollars, you could write your own functions.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Decided to go with using an int to store the change. And the only reason this isn't using functions/arrays is because I would actually get marked off since the instructor hasn't taught that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider working with integers. They're easier to work with, particularly when it comes to money.

```
double input_dollars;
// ...
long dollars = input_dollars * 100 + 0.5;  // in cents
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comment on using integers instead of doubles, but a quick fix is to change the line that calculate pennies from:

```
count = dollars / 0.01;
```

to:

```
count = round(dollars / 0.01);
```